# epplus from row insert

Tags: c#, epplus

i need to insert new row below to row with formatting like above row in excel using epplus!

after inserting row merge cell is disturb and data also unreadable

Please give me solution as soon as possible 
thanks

Comment: If you're in a hurry, write a better question. This is next to unintelligible. Needs more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming from row 1 going to row 2 you pass in the location of where you want the data

```
currentWorksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Totals";
```

If you wanted to merge, lets say cells A2 and B2 you would do the following

```
currentWorksheet.Cells["A2:B2"].Merge = true;
```

If you need more help, please be a little more descriptive